# How to return all values if Param is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-administration

I want to customize this stored procedure, That in case That param value @TownId is null returns all the data in the table. otherwise returns the correct data.
In my table there is no nulls in the TownId column. there is nvarchar values. 
i didn't success to get all the data if i send @TownId=null from the client side

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetCustomersPageWiseWithTown
@PageIndex INT = 1
  ,@PageSize INT = 10
  ,@PageCount INT OUTPUT
  ,@TownId int
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
              order by IsPaid desc
        )AS RowNumber
  ,b.Id
  ,b.Name
  ,b.Phone1
  ,b.Town
  ,b.Addess
  ,b.IsPaid
  ,b.DefaultImage
  ,t.TownName


INTO #Results
  FROM BusinessFullData b


  Left JOIN Towns t ON b.Town = t.Id 
   where  ((b.IsVisable=1) and (b.Town=@TownId))
  DECLARE @RecordCount INT
  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results

  SET @PageCount = CEILING(CAST(@RecordCount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(@PageSize AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
  PRINT       @PageCount

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results
RETURN
```

Thanks a lot for advise,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add that condition to your `WHERE` clause:

```
                             V-------------V
where  ((b.IsVisable=1) and (@TownId IS NULL OR b.Town=@TownId))
```

Also note that `IsVisible` is spelled wrong.

Comment: That not right, in this case nothing will returned, because there is no nulls in the TownId values in the table.

Comment: @user2274204 look again. The null check is on the parameter, not the table column.

Comment: @user2274204 It doesn't matter.  If the parameter is null then `@TownId IS NULL` will be true and the second condition has no impact.

Comment: Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

A better way of dealing with optional parameters is something like this...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetCustomersPageWiseWithTown
 @PageIndex INT = 1
,@PageSize  INT = 10
,@PageCount INT OUTPUT
,@TownId    INT
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);   
DECLARE @RecordCount INT;

SET @Sql = N'   
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by IsPaid desc)AS RowNumber
  ,b.Id
  ,b.Name
  ,b.Phone1
  ,b.Town
  ,b.Addess
  ,b.IsPaid
  ,b.DefaultImage
  ,t.TownName
               INTO #Results
  FROM BusinessFullData b
  Left JOIN Towns t ON b.Town = t.Id 
  where  b.IsVisable = 1 '
  + CASE WHEN @TownId IS NOT NULL 
   THEN N' and  b.Town = @TownId ' ELSE N'' END

  + N' SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*) FROM #Results

  SET @PageCount = CEILING(CAST(@RecordCount AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(@PageSize AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1'

Exec sp_executesql @Sql 
                  ,N'@PageIndex INT , @PageSize INT, @TownId int, 
                     @RecordCount INT, @PageCount INT OUTPUT'
                  ,@PageIndex
                  ,@PageSize
                  ,@TownId
                  ,@PageCount OUTPUT

END
```